# Create table from multiple columns in linux, but treat fields 2, 3 (and possibly 4) as one column

Tags: linux, bash, multiple-columns

Let's say I have the following file:

```
al.pacino Al Pacino
jerry.seinfeld     Jerry Seinfeld
chad.murray   Chad Michael Murray
```

I want to create a nice table with only two columns and treat the first name/middle name/last name as one column, like this:

```
al.pacino       Al Pacino
jerry.seinfeld  Jerry Seinfeld
chad.murray     Chad Michael Murray
```

The problem is that if I use the "column -t" command, each field will be treated as an individual column, which is not what I want:

```
al.pacino       Al     Pacino
jerry.seinfeld  Jerry  Seinfeld
chad.murray     Chad   Michael   Murray
```

Comment: Have you looked into `awk`?  Read your file into awk and then you have some control over your data so as to produce the formatted output that you need.

Comment: I did look into awk, but the only workaround I found was to extract the first two fields, create a table from those two, and then append the third / fourth fields with a "space" delimiter. But I feel like there should be a more elegant approach.

Comment: `column -t -s$'\t'` ? Separate your input fields by tabs.

Comment: Doesn't work either... especially when combining shorter with longer names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it with AWK, by reading the content from two variables (first one with login names and second with full names):

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[FNR] = $0 ; if (length > max) max = length ; next } { printf "%-*s  %s\n", max, a[FNR], $0 }' <(echo "${login_names}") <(echo "${full_names}")
```

The result is a nice looking, clean table no matter how different in length the names are:

```
christopher.reeve     Christopher Reeve
al.pacino             Al Pacino
jerry.seinfeld        Jerry Seinfeld
benedict.cumberbatch  Benedict Cumberbatch
chad.murray           Chad Michael Murray
```

Answer (score 3):

Insert a tab between the two columns with sed - feed this oneliner the input on stdin - the output will be two tab-delimited columns

```
sed -r 's/ +/\t/'
```

Comment: doesn't work OK in all situations, for example when   "cristopher.reeve        Christopher Reeve" is on the first line, instead of Al Pacino.

Comment: there's really nothing to this - is it possible there is other kind of whitespace e.g. tabs after the first column in the input? Can you tack on a cat -A and show the output?

Comment: There are only spaces between each column.